# How to make this string extension method work?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have this extension method, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly. The code is below.

```
public static bool string.isPalindrome()
{

}
```

I know what a palindrome is and have an idea on how to code this out, but how would I use this method in order to check whether a string is a palindrome?

Comment: That's not a valid extension method declaration, to start with... Why don't you start off by coding it *not* as an extension method, then read up on extension methods and convert it to one afterwards?

Comment: That was what my instructor gave me as what the method name should be, and we didn't really cover extension methods a whole lot. So thank you for the help.

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable method *name*, but the method *declaration* is invalid. There are *lots* of resources on extension methods on the web - did you look for any of them before asking the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use extension methods use the `this` keyword, as described in the [Extension Methods programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static bool isPalindrome(this string self)
{
    // use self parameter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension method you refer to isn't defined correctly in your original post. It should be defined like below:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(this string input)
{ 
    // Here you will place the code that will check 
    // if string called input is Palindrome.
}
```

By the way, you method should be included in a `static` class, like below:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsPalindrome(this string input)
    { 
        // Here you will place the code that will check 
        // if string called input is Palindrome.
    }
}
```

Last but not least, you could use it as below:

```
inputString.IsPalindrome();
```

where `inputString` is the string you want to check.

Comment: I didn't but I guess since your initial answer was wrong.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thank you very much, but I got two donwvotes a few minutes later my last update. Anyways than you very much.

Comment: I would drop the first part of your answer since it doesn't seem correct or helpful  to me.

Comment: @Christos And now the *last* part of your answer is incorrect. You can't use that extension method like that. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: that was the initial first part...

Comment: @J.Steen oops thank you very much ! I just corrected it !

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah, just moved to the bottom. I noticed. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to define a `isPalindrome()` extension onto the `String` class:

```
public static class MyExtension{ 
   public static bool isPalindrome(this string val){
        return val== new string(val.Reverse().ToArray());
   }
}
```